# What is the font used in this YouTube lyics video?

Tags: font-identification

I found this font used in [a YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0t30psT3dGo), but I had no luck to find its name.

[image]

Comment: Tricky one. I tried to run it through Whatthefont, which is the first level go-to, but the matches was not good. Hopefully someone else will come up with the actual answer, but next time, try whatthefont first. http://www.myfonts.com/

Comment: Looks like something you'd find on [dafont](http://www.dafont.com/) which is probably why WhatTheFont did not recognize it. The most logical person to ask would be the video creator, did you try that?

Comment: @JohnB of course we ask the video creator, but yet no answer.

Comment: @boblet I tried myfonts.com and two others, but fail to name the font.

Comment: Oh, good. It would be good though, next time, if you could mention that. It will make it a little more efficient and easier to give good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [**Alien League**](http://www.dafont.com/alien-league.font):

[image: Alien League font sample]

It looks like a sci-fi font to me, so I found it quickly by browsing [that category](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=303) on dafont. Typically, any "gimmicky" font like that can be found on dafont. It won't get recognized by WhatTheFont because it is not commercial (i.e. MyFonts won't make money off recognizing it)

Comment: Why the i letter looks different?

Comment: @SIFE the capital I and the lower case i have two different styles even though the font is an all-caps font. "Inside" has two different glyphs for "I" because of this.

Comment: @SIFE The capital I look different because that's how it looks on the 1986 movie poster for "Aliens" - which the font is heavily influenced by.